# How to place a second parameter to google.script.run.withSuccessHandler

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have the following working code:

`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getSelectOption).getSpreadsheetRange('16EBPA1TeOoMgn9fBmCJN8LwIMEGEYBSEvv17','OLT35A006T_PferdNameRange');`

Beside the result-array from `getSpreadsheetRange` I want to give a second parameter to `getSelectOption`. How can I do that?

Comment: The question begs for the what about n parameters and so the answer that I always use is to always return and object from the server and if it must be a date then I choose a date string format that can easily be handled by the Date() constructor to rebuild the date when necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about using `withUserObject(object)`? By this, you can retrieve the additional value at the function `getSelectOption`. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
google.script.run
.withUserObject("sample value")
.withSuccessHandler(getSelectOption)
.getSpreadsheetRange('16EBPA1TeOoMgn9fBmCJN8LwIMEGEYBSEvv17','OLT35A006T_PferdNameRange');

// By above modified script, you can retrieve `sample value` at the 2nd argument of `getSelectOption`.
function getSelectOption(a, b) {
  console.log(a)
  console.log(b)
}
```

- By above modified script, you can retrieve `sample value` at the 2nd argument of `getSelectOption`. The 1st argument of `getSelectOption` is from `getSpreadsheetRange`.
- Or, I think that the suggestion from the comment by [@doubleunary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69593649/how-to-place-a-second-parameter-to-google-script-run-withsuccesshandler/69593756?noredirect=1#comment123010663_69593756) can be also useful.
- Or, you can also use the function `getSelectOption` as follows. In this case, 2 arguments can be retrieved as an array.

  ```
    function getSelectOption(...a) {
      console.log(a[0])  // Return from "getSpreadsheetRange"
      console.log(a[1])  // Value from "withUserObject"
    }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [withUserObject(object)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withuserobjectobject)

### Edit:

From [the following doubleunary's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69593649/how-to-place-a-second-parameter-to-google-script-run-withsuccesshandler/69593756?noredirect=1#comment123015988_69593756)

> The way I read the question is that the OP wants to return two values from the server-side getSpreadsheetRange() to the client-side success handler getSelectOption(). When you call withUserObject(), the user object is never seen by the server-side function. When the success handler is called, it receives that unchanged server-side user object. To return two values from the client side, the client-side function needs to be modified so that it returns a compound object such as an array, or a key-value pair object.

I thought that I might have misunderstood the OP's goal. So, from the comment, I understood that when `getSpreadsheetRange()` is returned, OP wanted to add one more argument and wanted to use it at `getSelectOption()`.

In this case, I agree with doubleunary's comment and would like to propose the following modification.

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function getSpreadsheetRange(a, b) {

  // do something.

  return {arg1: "value1", arg2: "value2"}; // You can return the value as an object.
}
```

#### Javascript side:

```js
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(getSelectOption)
.getSpreadsheetRange('16EBPA1TeOoMgn9fBmCJN8LwIMEGEYBSEvv17','OLT35A006T_PferdNameRange');

function getSelectOption({arg1, arg2}) {
  console.log(arg1) // value1
  console.log(arg2) // value2
}
```

Comment: Would it not be simpler to just have `getSpreadsheetRange()` return something like `{ resultArray: result, anotherValue: anotherValue }` and modify `getSelectOption()` to accept a single object as parameter?

Comment: @doubleunary Thank you for your comment. I think that your suggestion can be also useful. When `getSpreadsheetRange()` returns such the object, the additional argument can be included. For example, when `withUserObject` is used, when `function getSelectOptiongetSelectOption(...a) {,,,}` is used, 2 argument values can be also retrieved as an array. For this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Agreed @Tanaike — an array as the return object should work fine. I have not used user objects because the documentation tells _"user objects are not sent to the server"_. Did not test that now so cannot tell for sure. Any objects passed between client and server apparently get JSON.stringified and re-parsed, so the usual issues with Date objects and `undefined`→`null` must be taken into account.

Comment: @doubleunary Thank you for replying. For example, when `.withUserObject({key1: "value1", key2: "value2"})` is used, `a[1]` of `getSelectOption(...a)` is the object of `{key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}`. So, `a[1].key1` returns `value1`. But, from `User objects cannot, however, be objects constructed with the new operator`, when the date object is sent, I think that it is required to convert it to the string and number as you say. I also think that this is an important point. This is the same with sending from Google Apps Script side by `google.script.run`.

Comment: The way I read the question is that the OP wants to return _two_ values from the server-side `getSpreadsheetRange()` to the client-side success handler `getSelectOption()`. When you call `withUserObject()`, the user object is never seen by the server-side function. When the success handler is called, it receives that _unchanged_ server-side user object. To return two values from the client side, the client-side function needs to be modified so that it returns a compound object such as an array, or a key-value pair object.

Comment: @doubleunary Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your comment, I could understand that my understanding was not correct. I had thought that OP wanted to add an argument at Javascript side. So I added one more sample modification. Could you please confirm it?